# C# Winform and Motorola MC9090-G implementation

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner, motorola-emdk

I really need help on implementing Motorola MC9090-G into our software application.
This is my first time to work on this project so I don't know where to start.
Any help would really be appreciated.

I already downloaded the EMDK for the barcode scanner (.net v2.4).
What I'm trying to accomplish now is just to connect the MC9090-G to my simple test application which only have a textbox in it.
Scan a barcode, Display the scanned barcode in the textbox and that's it! I'm just asking is someone could give me a step by step process on how I could do this? 
Most of the help that I'm getting from the internet is deploying an application in the scanner which I don't want to do for now.
I believe that doing this would be a great stepping stone for me!
so thanks in advance! :))

Comment: Just so you guys know, I end up using C# sockets which works really good for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Motorola's sample applications?  I found the sample applications included with the EMDK very instructive when learning this myself.  They have some very basic samples that make it pretty obvious the handful of lines of code that are needed to access the barcode scanner hardware.

Comment: Thank you for the response and yes I did. But all of them as far as I know is deploying the application into the device which I don't want. I want to run the application on my desktop. Connect the motorola mc9090-g using a cradle (USB connection) then scan a barcode then display it on a textbox (which is on the desktop screen not on the device screen).

Comment: Might I ask why you are using a fully functional mobile computer to accomplish this, rather than a much cheaper USB barcode scanner like the Motorola LS2208?

Comment: In any case, if that is your objective, I think that you will have to write an application that is resident on the MC9090 which reads the scanned data and then sends it (e.g. via TCP/IP) to a server application on the desktop computer that is listening for input.  The server app on the desktop would then populate the appropriate text box.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the only device available for me to use. Anyway, yes I think that is the way to go. (TCP/IP or Bluetooth) and there is a sample application included in the EMDK similar to this for me to look at. Do you know if its possible to transfer like a dataset from the host application (running off the desktop) to the application running off the device?

Comment: Thank you Scott for your replies. I am really new into this and just don't know where to start.

Comment: No problem.  Since the MC9090 is a full-fledge mobile computer, the possibilities are pretty wide open.  You can certainly design cooperating applications (one on device, one on desktop) that would send large sets of data back and forth.  It just comes down to designing your communications protocol appropriately so as to support sending the data that you need.

Comment: Ok, Thank you again and I'll try working towards that idea.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the most frustrating scanner I have ever played with.

(Give me a dumb scanner that acts like an HID Keyboard any day!)

I wrote a small App that includes a Text Box, List Box, and a button or two.

Basically, the Scanner Wedge will place the scanned data into what ever has focus.

One of the problems I had was knowing when the scanner data was completer. So, I added a timer.

The next problem, and one that I have found *no* easy solution to is getting the data off the scanner and into a *real* computer, whether Linux of Windows based.

Windows Mobile Device Center and Active Sync require too much operator interaction.

The best I've come up with is to open a Hyper Terminal Window. But, it's all a kludge.

So, far I've had no luck using Blue Tooth either. My form code is below. Hope it helps. This is a modification to one of their Samples. I am using EMDK 2.8

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// FILENAME: Form1.cs
//
// Copyright © 2011 Motorola Solutions, Inc. All rights reserved.
//
// DESCRIPTION:
//
// NOTES:
//
// 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Symbol.Barcode;
using Symbol.Barcode2;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace CS_Barcode2ControlSample1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

        private static bool bPortrait = true;   // The default dispaly orientation 
        // has been set to Portrait.

        private bool bSkipMaxLen = false;    // The restriction on the maximum 
        // physical length is considered by default.

        private bool bInitialScale = true;   // The flag to track whether the 
        // scaling logic is applied for
        // the first time (from scatch) or not.
        // Based on that, the (outer) width/height values
        // of the form will be set or not.
        // Initially set to true.

        private int resWidthReference = 240;   // The (cached) width of the form. 
        // INITIALLY HAS TO BE SET TO THE WIDTH OF THE FORM AT DESIGN TIME (IN PIXELS).
        // This setting is also obtained from the platform only on
        // Windows CE devices before running the application on the device, as a 

verification.
        // For PocketPC (& Windows Mobile) devices, the failure to set this properly may 

result in the distortion of GUI/viewability.

        private int resHeightReference = 268;  // The (cached) height of the form.
        // INITIALLY HAS TO BE SET TO THE HEIGHT OF THE FORM AT DESIGN TIME (IN PIXELS).
        // This setting is also obtained from the platform only on
        // Windows CE devices before running the application on the device, as a 

verification.
        // For PocketPC (& Windows Mobile) devices, the failure to set this properly may 

result in the distortion of GUI/viewability.

        private const double maxLength = 5.5;  // The maximum physical width/height of 

the sample (in inches).
        // The actual value on the device may slightly deviate from this
        // since the calculations based on the (received) DPI & resolution values 
        // would provide only an approximation, so not 100% accurate.


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Interval = 100;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function does the (initial) scaling of the form
        /// by re-setting the related parameters (if required) &
        /// then calling the Scale(...) internally. 
        /// </summary>
        /// 
        public void DoScale()
        {
            if (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
            {
                bPortrait = false; // If the display orientation is not portrait (so it's 

landscape), set the flag to false.
            }

            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)    // If the form is 

maximized by default.
            {
                this.bSkipMaxLen = true; // we need to skip the max. length restriction
            }

            if ((Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("WinCE") != -1) || 

(Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("WindowsCE") != -1) || 

(Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("Windows CE") != -1)) // Only on Windows CE devices
            {
                this.resWidthReference = this.Width;   // The width of the form at design 

time (in pixels) is obtained from the platorm.
                this.resHeightReference = this.Height; // The height of the form at 

design time (in pixels) is obtained from the platform.
            }

            Scale(this); // Initial scaling of the GUI
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function scales the given Form & its child controls in order to
        /// make them completely viewable, based on the screen width & height.
        /// </summary>
        private static void Scale(Form1 frm)
        {
            int PSWAW = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;    

// The width of the working area (in pixels).
            int PSWAH = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;   

// The height of the working area (in pixels).

            // The entire screen has been taken in to account below 
            // in order to decide the half (S)VGA settings etc.
            if (!((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width <= (1.5) * 

(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
            && (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height <= (1.5) * 

(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width))))
            {
                if ((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) > 

(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
                {
                    PSWAW = (int)((1.33) * PSWAH);  // If the width/height ratio goes 

beyond 1.5,
                    // the (longer) effective width is made shorter.
                }

            }

            System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = frm.CreateGraphics();

            float dpiX = graphics.DpiX; // Get the horizontal DPI value.

            if (frm.bInitialScale == true) // If an initial scale (from scratch)
            {
                if (Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("PocketPC") != -1) // If the 

platform is either Pocket PC or Windows Mobile
                {
                    frm.Width = PSWAW;  // Set the form width. However this setting
                    // would be the ultimate one for Pocket PC (& Windows Mobile)devices.
                    // Just for the sake of consistency, it's explicitely specified here.
                }
                else
                {
                    frm.Width = (int)((frm.Width) * (PSWAW)) / (frm.resWidthReference); 

// Set the form width for others (Windows CE devices).

                }
            }
            if ((frm.Width <= maxLength * dpiX) || frm.bSkipMaxLen == true) // The 

calculation of the width & left values for each control
            // without taking the maximum length restriction into consideration.
            {
                foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl in frm.Controls)
                {
                    cntrl.Width = ((cntrl.Width) * (frm.Width)) / 

(frm.resWidthReference);
                    cntrl.Left = ((cntrl.Left) * (frm.Width)) / (frm.resWidthReference);

                    if (cntrl is System.Windows.Forms.TabControl)
                    {
                        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPg in cntrl.Controls)
                        {
                            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl2 in 

tabPg.Controls)
                            {
                                cntrl2.Width = (((cntrl2.Width) * (frm.Width)) / 

(frm.resWidthReference));
                                cntrl2.Left = (((cntrl2.Left) * (frm.Width)) / 

(frm.resWidthReference));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {   // The calculation of the width & left values for each control
                // with the maximum length restriction taken into consideration.
                foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl in frm.Controls)
                {
                    cntrl.Width = (int)(((cntrl.Width) * (PSWAW) * (maxLength * dpiX)) / 

(frm.resWidthReference * (frm.Width)));
                    cntrl.Left = (int)(((cntrl.Left) * (PSWAW) * (maxLength * dpiX)) / 

(frm.resWidthReference * (frm.Width)));

                    if (cntrl is System.Windows.Forms.TabControl)
                    {
                        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPg in cntrl.Controls)
                        {
                            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl2 in 

tabPg.Controls)
                            {
                                cntrl2.Width = (int)(((cntrl2.Width) * (PSWAW) * 

(maxLength * dpiX)) / (frm.resWidthReference * (frm.Width)));
                                cntrl2.Left = (int)(((cntrl2.Left) * (PSWAW) * (maxLength 

* dpiX)) / (frm.resWidthReference * (frm.Width)));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                frm.Width = (int)((frm.Width) * (maxLength * dpiX)) / (frm.Width);

            }

            frm.resWidthReference = frm.Width; // Set the reference width to the new 

value.


            // A similar calculation is performed below for the height & top values for 

each control ...

            if (!((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width <= (1.5) * 

(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
            && (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height <= (1.5) * 

(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width))))
            {
                if ((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) > 

(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width))
                {
                    PSWAH = (int)((1.33) * PSWAW);
                }

            }

            float dpiY = graphics.DpiY;

            if (frm.bInitialScale == true)
            {
                if (Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("PocketPC") != -1)
                {
                    frm.Height = PSWAH;
                }
                else
                {
                    frm.Height = (int)((frm.Height) * (PSWAH)) / 

(frm.resHeightReference);

                }
            }

            if ((frm.Height <= maxLength * dpiY) || frm.bSkipMaxLen == true)
            {
                foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl in frm.Controls)
                {

                    cntrl.Height = ((cntrl.Height) * (frm.Height)) / 

(frm.resHeightReference);
                    cntrl.Top = ((cntrl.Top) * (frm.Height)) / (frm.resHeightReference);


                    if (cntrl is System.Windows.Forms.TabControl)
                    {
                        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPg in cntrl.Controls)
                        {
                            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl2 in 

tabPg.Controls)
                            {
                                cntrl2.Height = ((cntrl2.Height) * (frm.Height)) / 

(frm.resHeightReference);
                                cntrl2.Top = ((cntrl2.Top) * (frm.Height)) / 

(frm.resHeightReference);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl in frm.Controls)
                {

                    cntrl.Height = (int)(((cntrl.Height) * (PSWAH) * (maxLength * dpiY)) 

/ (frm.resHeightReference * (frm.Height)));
                    cntrl.Top = (int)(((cntrl.Top) * (PSWAH) * (maxLength * dpiY)) / 

(frm.resHeightReference * (frm.Height)));


                    if (cntrl is System.Windows.Forms.TabControl)
                    {
                        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TabPage tabPg in cntrl.Controls)
                        {
                            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Control cntrl2 in 

tabPg.Controls)
                            {
                                cntrl2.Height = (int)(((cntrl2.Height) * (PSWAH) * 

(maxLength * dpiY)) / (frm.resHeightReference * (frm.Height)));
                                cntrl2.Top = (int)(((cntrl2.Top) * (PSWAH) * (maxLength * 

dpiY)) / (frm.resHeightReference * (frm.Height)));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

                frm.Height = (int)((frm.Height) * (maxLength * dpiY)) / (frm.Height);

            }

            frm.resHeightReference = frm.Height;

            if (frm.bInitialScale == true)
            {
                frm.bInitialScale = false; // If this was the initial scaling (from 

scratch), it's now complete.
            }
            if (frm.bSkipMaxLen == true)
            {
                frm.bSkipMaxLen = false; // No need to consider the maximum length 

restriction now.
            }


        }

        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // You must disable the scanner before exiting the application in 
            // order to release all the resources.
            barcode21.EnableScanner = false;
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }
        private void buttonExit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            // Checks if the key pressed was an enter button (character code 13)
            if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
                buttonExit_Click(this, e);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Add MainMenu if Pocket PC
            if (Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("PocketPC") != -1)
            {
                this.Menu = this.mainMenu1;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bInitialScale == true)
            {
                return; // Return if the initial scaling (from scratch)is not complete.
            }

            if (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) 

// If landscape orientation
            {
                if (bPortrait != false) // If an orientation change has occured to 

landscape
                {
                    bPortrait = false; // Set the orientation flag accordingly.
                    bInitialScale = true; // An initial scaling is required due to 

orientation change.
                    Scale(this); // Scale the GUI.
                }
                else
                {   // No orientation change has occured
                    bSkipMaxLen = true; // Initial scaling is now complete, so skipping 

the max. length restriction is now possible.
                    Scale(this); // Scale the GUI.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Similarly for the portrait orientation...
                if (bPortrait != true)
                {
                    bPortrait = true;
                    bInitialScale = true;
                    Scale(this);
                }
                else
                {
                    bSkipMaxLen = true;
                    Scale(this);
                }
            }

        }

        private void barcode21_OnScan(ScanDataCollection scanDataCollection)
        {
            // Checks if the BeginInvoke method is required because the 

OnScan delegate is called by a different thread
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Executes the OnScan delegate asynchronously on the 

main thread
                this.BeginInvoke(new Symbol.Barcode2.Design.Barcode2.OnScanEventHandler

(barcode21_OnScan), new object[] { scanDataCollection });
            }
            else
            {
                ScanData scanData = scanDataCollection.GetFirst;
                if (scanData.Result == Results.SUCCESS)
                {
                    // Write the scanned data and type (symbology) to the list box
                    //listBox1.Items.Add(scanData.Text + ";" + scanData.Type.ToString());
                    string sData = scanData.Text;
                    // IUID Snowflake Header
                    if (sData.StartsWith("[)>"))
                    {
                        // Process IUID Scan Data
                        string unkStr = iuidScan(sData);
                    }
                    else if (sData.StartsWith("N"))
                    {
                        // Probable CAC Card Reading
                        txt2Send.Text = sData;
                        lstStatus.Items.Add("Probable CAC Scanned");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Anything Else
                        txt2Send.Text = sData;
                        lstStatus.Items.Add("Unknown");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void barcode21_OnStatus(StatusData statusData)
        {
            // Checks if the BeginInvoke method is required because the 

OnStatus delegate is called by a different thread
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Executes the OnStatus delegate asynchronously on the 

main thread
                this.BeginInvoke(new 

Symbol.Barcode2.Design.Barcode2.OnStatusEventHandler(barcode21_OnStatus), new object[] { 

statusData });
            }
            else
            {
                statusBar1.Text = statusData.Text;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            barcode21.EnableScanner = false;
            this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Port has to be Open to test DSR
            port.Open();
            if (port.DsrHolding == true)
            {
                btnTransmit.Text = "Click To Transmit Data";
                btnTransmit.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                btnTransmit.Text = "Not Connected";
                btnTransmit.Enabled = false;
            }
            port.Close();
        }

        private void btnTransmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            port.Open();
            port.Write(txt2Send.Text);
            port.Write(new byte[] { 0x0A, 0x0D }, 0, 2);
            port.Close();
            txt2Send.Text = "";
            lstStatus.Items.Clear();
        }

        // A method for expanding ASCII Control Character into Human Readable format
        string ExpandCtrlString(string inStr)
        {
            // String Builder Capacity may need to be lengthened...
            StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder(128);
            // 0 Based Array representing the expansion of ASCII Control Characters
            string[] CtrlChars = new string[]
            {
                "<nul>",
                "<soh>",
                "<stx>",
                "<etx>",
                "<eot>",
                "<enq>",
                "<ack>",
                "<bel>",
                "<bs>",
                "<tab>",
                "<lf>",
                "<vt>",
                "<ff>",
                "<cr>",
                "<so>",
                "<si>",
                "<dle>",
                "<dc1>",
                "<dc2>",
                "<dc3>",
                "<dc4>",
                "<nak>",
                "<syn>",
                "<etb>",
                "<can>",
                "<em>",
                "<sub>",
                "<esc>",
                "<fs>",
                "<gs>",
                "<rs>",
                "<us>"
            };

            for (int n = 0; n < inStr.Length; n++)
            {
                if (Char.IsControl(inStr, n))
                {
                    int x = (int)(char)inStr[n];
                    outStr.Append(CtrlChars[x]);
                }
                else
                {
                    outStr.Append(inStr.Substring(n, 1));
                }
            }
            return outStr.ToString();
        }

        // IUID Data Was Scanned
        string iuidScan(string sData)
        {
            // We will temporarily Display an Expanded version of the Scanned Data
            txt2Send.Text = ExpandCtrlString(sData);
            lstStatus.Items.Add("IUID Scanned");
            // Get the format type
            string iuidFormat = sData.Substring(4, 2);
            lstStatus.Items.Add("Format: " + iuidFormat);

            // We are NOT currently supporting formats other than format 6
            if (iuidFormat != "06")
            {
                lstStatus.Items.Add("Unacceptable Format!");
                return "No Data";
            }
            string iuidType = sData.Substring(7, 3);
            string iuidConstruct = "0";
            // Have to If Else If because the iuidType is variable length
            string rData = "No Data";
            int kw = 10;    // 10 for start position when iuidType is 3 Characters
            switch(iuidType)
            {
                case "18S":
                case "25S":
                case "22S":
                    iuidConstruct = "1";
                    rData = iuidConstruct1(sData, kw);
                    break;
                case "17V":
                case "12V":
                case "18V":
                    iuidConstruct = "2";
                    rData = iuidConstruct2(sData, kw);
                    break;
                default:
                    // Single and Two Digit Construct ID's not yet supported
                    iuidConstruct = "Unknown";
                    break;
            }
            lstStatus.Items.Add("Construct Identifier: " + iuidType);
            lstStatus.Items.Add("Construct: " + iuidConstruct);
            return "No data";
        }
        // Extraction Routine for IUID Construct 1
        string iuidConstruct1(string sData, int kw)
        {
            // Must Check for Concatenated Data
            int gsIndex = sData.IndexOf("\u001D", kw);
            if (gsIndex < 0)
            {
                gsIndex = sData.IndexOf("\u001E", kw);
                lstStatus.Items.Add("Does Not Have Appended Data");
            }
            else
            {
                lstStatus.Items.Add("Has Appended Data");
            }

            string UII = "UII: D" + sData.Substring(kw, gsIndex - kw);
            string root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            lstStatus.Items.Add("Root Path: " + root);
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"\My Documents

\MDMC.txt");
            string line;
            int counter = 0;
            int sl = UII.Length;
            line = file.ReadLine();
            lstStatus.Items.Add("Searching Database");
            while (line != null)
            {
                lstStatus.Items.Add(line);
                lstStatus.Refresh();

                if (line.Length >= sl)
                {
                    if (line.Substring(0, sl) == UII)
                    {

                        lstStatus.Items.Add("Counter: " + counter);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ((counter % 100) == 0)
                {
                    lstStatus.Items.Add("Counter: " + counter);
                    lstStatus.Refresh();
                }
                line = file.ReadLine();
                counter++;
                if (counter >= 1000)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            file.Close();

            //txt2Send.Text = "kw: " + kw + " gsIndex: " + gsIndex + "\n\rsData: " + 

sData + "\n\rsData: " + UII; 

            return "No Data";
        }

        // Extraction Routine for IUID Construct 2
        string iuidConstruct2(string sData, int kw)
        {
            // iuidConstruct = "2";
            int gsIndex = 0;
            string iuidEID = "Unknown"; // Enterprise Identifier. Often the CAGE Code
            gsIndex = sData.IndexOf("\u001D", kw);
            iuidEID = sData.Substring(10, gsIndex - kw);
            lstStatus.Items.Add(iuidEID);
            if (sData.Substring(gsIndex + 1, 2) == "1P")
            {
                // Serial Number Applies
                kw = gsIndex + 3;
                gsIndex = sData.IndexOf("\u001D", kw);
                string PartNumber = sData.Substring(kw, gsIndex - kw);
                // We are asumming that a "S" exists after the <gs>
                kw = gsIndex + 2;
                // Must Check for <gs> because may contain Appended Data
                // Returns -1 if <gs> not found, indicating no appended data.
                gsIndex = sData.IndexOf("\u001D", kw);
                if (gsIndex < 0)
                {
                    gsIndex = sData.IndexOf("\u001E", kw);
                }
                else
                {
                    lstStatus.Items.Add("Has Appended Data");
                }

                string SerialNumber = sData.Substring(kw, gsIndex - kw);
                txt2Send.Text = "Gage: " + iuidEID + "\n\rPart Number: " + PartNumber + 

"\n\rSerial Number: " + SerialNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                // Assume '1T'. Serialization within Lot/Batch

            }
            return "No Data";
        }


    }
}
```